# Antivirus automatically get switched off after hibernation

Tags: windows, hibernate

Yesterday (7.12), i updated my windows defender as it was an important update and then i thought everything was alright. I left my laptop into hibernation and switch it on twice, it was okay, nothing happened.

But today, after i came back from work, i switch my com back from hibernation, the security center suddenly warned me that my antivirus is off, i did not do anything to off the antivirus, i merely left my com in hibernation mode.

Its my first time experiencing such situation, i'm worried, please advise. thank you.

Comment: What antivirus are you using? What version of Windows are you using? What are the specs of the computer? Please provide more information.

Comment: is the update still ok and has it happened again, say from reboot, one off's happen.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to uninstall your antivirus and learn how to surf safely. Antivirus programs are resource hogs. I try not to use hibernation either because it tends to be buggy as you describe, and my laptop is older and I don't have a lot of room for all the disk space hibernation requires (I understand it saves the contents of ram to the disk, which can take up a considerable amount of space depending on your setup).

Proof it can be buggy [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)#Problems_with_hibernation).

Proof it takes up space is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ocurred with me. I always use hibernation and when I used AVG sometimes it turned off after hibernation. So I installed another antivirus: Avast; the issue was fixed. So that is a problem of your antivirus software. Update that and report the error to vendor. Or change the software.